# Finding Unstressed Schwa

Tags: american-english, vowels

In our country, we really don’t have the “unstressed schwa”

How do I find this one? is there a technique?

How do I find the unstressed schwa with these word? Thanks

1. occur
2. history
3. curious
4. actor
5. frozen

Comment: Dictionaries have pronunciation guides, which they explain.

Comment: Replace the vowel sounds, one at a time, with an apostrophe: Say the word with the apostrophe. Which word sounds closest to the original word? ++ occur > 'ccur ? occ'r. ++ history > h'story > hist'ry, etc.

Comment: An "unstressed schwa" before a resonant (/m, n, ŋ, l, r/) is frequently converted into a syllabic resonant with no schwa vowel at all. (5) is a good example; it's pronounced /'fro:zn/ in American English, with the final /n/ pronounced as a syllable.

Comment: If it helps you, in Hebrew, there's a *moving schwa* that is so slight, it's the non-syllable between the F and R of FRozen. So that's a very unstressed schwa.

Answer (score 1):

There are dictionaries online that allow input of an English word and it will show the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA).

[IPA — Speech Active](https://www.speechactive.com/in-the-international-phonetic-alphabet-ipa-what-does-%C9%99-mean/)

> What is /ə/ in the dictionary? The symbol /ə/ (an upside down ‘e’) is
>   used in the dictionary to show the most common weak vowel in English,
>   which is pronounced as a relaxed ‘uh’. /ə/ is called ‘schwa’.

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/frozen?s=t)

On this site, after inputting the word, one needs to click "Show IPA" to get that result.